# How to pull out certain value using php and this output

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I've come across a weird scenario I do not know how to code around. I'm creating a JSON API for a wordpress site. I'm using the Connections plugin and trying to pull out the "original" image filename. The output of my sql command is this:

```
{
    ["options"]=>
    string(396) "a:4:{s:5:"entry";a:1:{s:4:"type";s:12:"organization";}s:5:"group";a:1:{s:6:"family";a:0:{}}s:4:"logo";a:2:{s:6:"linked";b:0;s:7:"display";b:0;}s:5:"image";a:3:{s:6:"linked";b:1;s:7:"display";b:1;s:4:"name";a:4:{s:9:"thumbnail";s:25:"invoicelogo_thumbnail.jpg";s:5:"entry";s:21:"invoicelogo_entry.jpg";s:7:"profile";s:23:"invoicelogo_profile.jpg";s:8:"original";s:24:"invoicelogo_original.jpg";}}}"
  }
}
```

I'm using the following command to acquire that:

```
querystr = "SELECT options FROM {$wpdb->prefix}connections WHERE id= '{$_GET['companyID']}'"; 
    $options = $wpdb->get_results($querystr);
```

I'm not sure how to pull out the "original" part of this code though as it's not all that organized. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is the results of a php `serialize` call

To get at the original name just do this.

```
$decodedOptions = unserialize($options);
$original = $decodedOptions["image"]["name"]["original"];
```

Hope that helps

As a side note the deserialized data looks like

```
Array
(
    [entry] => Array
        (
            [type] => organization
        )

    [group] => Array
        (
            [family] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [logo] => Array
        (
            [linked] => 
            [display] => 
        )

    [image] => Array
        (
            [linked] => 1
            [display] => 1
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [thumbnail] => invoicelogo_thumbnail.jpg
                    [entry] => invoicelogo_entry.jpg
                    [profile] => invoicelogo_profile.jpg
                    [original] => invoicelogo_original.jpg
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you, I had forgotten completely that WordPress does that. I can't accept your answer within 5 minute according to stackoverflow. Will do so when it lets me. Thanks again!